# Is udelay deterministic if I disable preemption and irq?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I use udelay to control the GPIO signal toggling time. I disabled preemption and interrupt using preempt_disable and local_irq_disable. However the test shows from time to time the delay caused by udelay is longer than I expected. I am running on a dual core ARM system. May I know if the udelay time is deterministic and accurate under all system condition as long as I disable preemption and interrupt? If not, any suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

udelay (and mdelay) work by spinning (a busy wait), and use the bogomips value to determine the spin count.  Considering that modern processors won't execute instructions deterministically, because of cache misses, pipelines, branch prediction misses, variable memory latency, etc, I would hypothesize that udelay will not be deterministic, even if you disable hardware interrupts.

If your platform has some sort of high performance timer (like the Time Stamp Counter on intel CPUs), you may be able to get that to work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any suggestion on an ARM system? (to be more specific, Samsung Exynos 4210?) Thanks again